# Deploy ASP.Net Website and REST Web Service in Plesk (GoDaddy)

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, publish, plesk

I managed to deploy my website in Plesk, but how do I deploy my REST web service? Which folder should I put it in? Should I buy another hosting just for the web service?

[image: ASP.Net Website deployed to Plesk]

Comment: Do you have a separate project for your rest api or is it part of your website? On your development machine, website and rest api run on different ports of localhost? If answer to these questions is yes then you need to deploy your rest service as separate website/app on the hosting.

Comment: My REST API is a different project from my website, both are different ports. Thank you for your reply. So to save money, it would be better if I just host my website on a free hosting site then retain the API together with the database in GoDaddy? This is for educational purposes only.

Comment: Yeah if your website only access data  using API then you can host it on free hosting